# HSV Hue value is inconsistent. Why?

Tags: color, shader-nodes

Can someone explain how Blender HSV works since it doesn't work as normal HSV should. Hue value 0-1 should be 360 deg so 1/4 value should be 90 deg. but somehow it's less? Then again 1/2 is 180 deg, as it should. But once again with 270deg in Blender it's 0.7 when it actually should be 0.75 This makes no sense. I'm lost. Any idea?

I also checked Blender manual. Blender manual says this: "Hue: Specifies the hue rotation of the image. 360° are mapped to (0 to 1)." This is from "Hue Saturation Value Node", but it was the only manual page what defined Hue mapping in Blender. It should follow the same logic in any HSV mapping.

Currently in Blender:

0.300 is 90 deg

0.500 is 180 deg

0.700 is 270 deg

1.000 is 360 deg

When logic says:

0.250 is 90 deg

0.500 is 180 deg

0.750 is 270 deg

1.000 is 360 deg

What? Why?

[image]

Comment: What version are you using? Might be worth reporting it as a bug.

Comment: Newest Blender 3.0.1 that had bunch of bug fixes @Onyx

Comment: Not absolutely sure, so not an answer, but what makes sense to me is:   the system is based on RGB, the translation from HSV to RGB is non-linear, and so getting the angles to be _geometrically_  correct would involve changing the entire  color-disk. That would be a more intrusive inconsistency than allowing the angles to be out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a deliberate choice to make certain reagions wider and easier to pick from
Adobe's Color wheel has a similar inconsistency

*"It's not a bug, it's a feature!"*

[image]